# Security of master password in a derived password manager

Tags: password-management, password-cracking

I am aware of other questions asking similar things as this one, but I believe this design addresses many of the issues raised in those questions. I'm also not concerned with making sure there's no database to store, only that the database doesn't store any secrets.

```
Using some key derivation function KDF
With master password provided from elsewhere
Password requirements are the rules of what are allowed by the site,
    i.e. length, allowed character classes, required classes

# To register with a new site
With username provided from elsewhere
With password requirements provided from elswhere
Create a salt
Store site,password requirements,username,salt
Create key by KDF(salt, master password)
Convert key to generated password to fit password requirements
Give username and generated password to site
Register

# To login to a site
Retrieve password requirements,username,salt by site
Create key by KDF(salt, master password)
Convert key to generated password to fit password requirements
Give username and generated password to site
Login
```

Let's say an attacker acquires both the store and the plaintext generated passwords.

1. Does this design make it any easier for the attacker to find the master password than by a brute force attack?
2. Is a brute force attack on this design easier than a brute force attack on an encrypted password store?
3. Is this in any other way easier to attack than encrypted password managers that derive the encryption key from a master password?

Of course the list of sites and usernames itself is important information. I'm only wondering about the security of the master password.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Does this design make it any easier for the attacker to find the master password than by a brute force attack?

No. Not that I see.

> (2) Is a brute force attack on this design easier than a brute force attack on an encrypted password store?

Yes. There is more ways for an attacker to obtain the data that they need for a brute force attack. At least that is the case if we take your notion that there are no secrets in your database.

Suppose I set up a server for, say, `MyCuteKittyPictures.net`, and I store passwords on that server in plaintext. There are plenty of plaintext offenders out there anyway. An evil site operator or anyone who compromises a plaintext offender, is able to learn your password for that site.

This gives them everything that they need to launch a brute force attack except the salt, but you have said that the database file is not a secret, and therefore I should assume that the attacker has access to the salt.

In my example, I talked about a single plaintext offender (and a malicious one), but data from any plaintext offender puts the attacker in a position to launch a brute force attack. And so there is more opportunity to an attacker obtain enough data to launch such attacks

> (3) Is this in any other way easier to attack than encrypted password managers that derive the encryption key from a master password?

This is going to depend on some fine details. But on the whole encrypted password managers will generate passwords that are truly independent of each other.

Also what you are calling encrypted password managers will have the ability to encrypt the site, and username, and other data which a user may wish to keep private. I may not want to world to know whether I have a login for `ToenailChewersAnon.org` or that I am user `fluffybuns` on some other site.

So you really aren't gaining anything by pursuing yet another attempt at a derived password manager. And you are losing other desirable processes.

Comment: Regarding #2, say you're using a KeePass database. Securely storing that database is the same problem as securing my plaintext store, so let's assume an attacker has the encrypted database too. Is the encrypted database still less vulnerable to brute force attack?

Answer (score 0):

The weakest point appears to be your "stored information", which contains the possible rules for your passwords. So, for example, if the attacker knew that your password for *example.com* must be generated as a case insensitive 12-char string, this information will be useful to set up a more efficient bruteforce attack on *example.com*. The security of your master password won't be affected in any way though.

For the master password, there's the KDF to consider. If your KDF is secure enough (not known to have weaknesses and taking enough time or memory to be computed), then an attacker cannot get the master password without bruteforcing it, even if they knew the salt or any other information about how you create the final password. But if your KDF is not secure enough (maybe you just use plain SHA for your custom KDF, for example), then bruteforcing your master password might be much easier than bruteforcing the master password of a good password manager (good password managers rely on functions and algorithms that are known to be secure).